# Outlook and "reply all" to a mailing list

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I am on a mailing list with members of my development team.  For ease of communicating with our customers, the mailing list is configured to accept traffic from anyone at our company even if they are not members of the list.

When a customer sends mail to our list, my Outlook client displays the customer's name as the sender, however the real From address is the list, and so when and I hit "reply all" in Outlook, my reply goes to the list but not to the customer, which is frustrating.

Is there a way around this?  Perhaps some setting in Outlook or in the back-end mailing list software (which I believe is Sympa)?

Answer (score 0):

I want to confirm if your mail server is exchange server? and the mail list is distribution group?

In general, in the outlook side, the custom will appear in To filed when you click the reply all button. This is outlook default behavior. Could this issue occur to other users? If not, you could try to disable the Sympa and check if this issue continues. Since I'm not familiar with Sympa, you'd better get further assistant from Sympa support team.